# Shiro login redirects with fragment identifiers

Tags: shiro

We are writing a Java based webapp with Shiro as the authentication framework and came across a redirect issue.

On login redirects the fragment ids get lost:

- /workspace#documents/... (fragment id is not submitted, which is normal HTTP behaviour)
- /login#documents/... (fragment id is reappended by browser after redirect)
- /workspace (Shiro redirects to base url)

Has anyone figured out a simple solution to preserve the fragment identifier across the login redirects?

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but just in case.

The url should preserve the hash id if you let shiro handle the redirects. If you roll your own redirect they that might be the problem.

Here is a sample app that proves hash ids are persisted after log in redirect.

https://github.com/dominicfarr/skybird-shiro

See Preserve Hash id in ReadME